# Is there a brewing software that supports late additions?

Tags: calculations, software

Promash doesn't support late addition of extracts (which affects hop extraction).  Either that, or I can't find out how to do it.

I sometimes use [beercalculus.hopville.com](http://beercalculus.hopville.com) to create two recipes, one without the late addition, from which I take the IBUs, and one with the late addition, from which I take the OG.

Is there any software out there that will allow me to note when fermentables go into the boil?

**UPDATE**: [hopville.com](http://hopville.com) has supported late additions since shortly after I asked this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beersmith currently allows for late addition of extract.  And it allows you to enter the time at which you are entering it.

Promash is popular, but worthless when it comes to updates.

Beersmith is supposed to  be coming out with an update later in the summer, just something to keep in mind if you chose to buy a copy.

Comment: Agreed, Beersmith is an excellent choice and does late additions.  It is what I use.

Comment: I absolutely love Beersmith. There are some great features coming in the pipeline, and he even supports Linux!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Mac user, [Beer Alchemy](http://www.kentplacesoftware.com/products/BeerAlchemy.html) from Kent Place Software is excellent. The have some support for late additions as all ingredients have a 'when added' column. For fermentables, the options are in the mash/steeped, start of boil and end of boil.

Answer (score 0):

www.brewersfriend.com has an online recipe utility allowing for late additions.